# How to track the DDL changes in MSsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ddl

I need to create the stored procedure in mssql to track the ddl changes. If any ddl changes occured like new table create, new column added, altered exisitng column, drop column then procedure should track these changes and insert into new table. I tired multiple ways but i couldn't get the details of recently added or altered columns. Can i get any help here?

Query tried:

```
Select
  object_name(sc.object_id) as tablename,
  sc.name,
  so.modify_date,
  so.create_date
from sys.all_columns sc
joon sys.objects so on sc.object_id = so.object_id
where tablename = 'A'
order by so.modify_date desc
```

This query listed all the columns in table A but modify_date and create_date is same for all column (i know it applied table modified date for all column but i want to identified when the column altered)

Comment: A procedure isn't going to do this, you'll need a database trigger. Though *why* do you need to do this? What question are you trying to answer by storing this information?

Comment: you shouldn't try multiple ways. There is only one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: There are audit logs, extended events, database triggers,  change data capture, replication. More that I can't remember right now. While all capture DDL changes they do it for different reasons. Auditing is used to create security audits. Extended events are used for real-time monitoring and profiling. CDC is used to capture data changes so they can be sent to other systems for eg reporting and data warehousing. Replication is used to keep multiple databases in sync

Comment: What question are you trying to answer by storing this information? I to need capture this from source DB and same needs to apply in downtreams

Comment: `same needs to apply in downtreams` that's what replication and CDC do. You don't have to do it by hand. And if you try to, you'll probably have to reinvent the entire feature. Simply copying data sounds simple, but how are you going to monitor this? Get notified of failures?

Comment: You need a code management tool first.

Comment: If you want to find differences between two databases you can use the `Schema Difference` tool in Azure Data Studio to find the differences between a source and target database and generate a script that applies those changes to the target database. You can also extract the schema as a `dacpac` (Data Tier Application) and diff between the dacpac and target databases

Comment: Perhaps what you really need is a change management tool (and good source control) with migration processes for deploying to multiple instances.